# Is there a concept of an implicit subject to be passed to an rspec matcher?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Say I have a custom matcher that checks to see if an object is a valid RGB tuple -- let's call it `valid_rgb_tuple`.  The matcher takes an object as an argument and validates it.  I'd like to be able to use that in a oneliner where the `subject` is expected to be a tuple.  Ideally that would look/read something like this:

```
subject { some_method_that_should_return_a_tuple }
it { should be_a_valid_rgb_tuple }
```

I'm not sure how to make that work, or if it's even possible to get close.  I think I need a way to force the subject to get automatically passed into the validator.  Is there a construct for this?

**UPDATE:**

This turned out just to be a problem with the way I defined the matcher.  I did something like this:

```ruby
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_valid_rgb_tuple do |color|
  match do
    begin
      # check the color value
    end
  end
end
```

Which is incorrect because of how `color` is passed.  It needs to be redone like so:

```ruby
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_valid_rgb_tuple do
  match do |color|
    begin
      # check the color value
    end
  end
end
```

Note how the value is passed to the block provided to the match method.  In the first case, the color argument is an argument to the call to `be_a_valid_rgb_tuple` that *creates* the matcher, whereas in the second it's the implicit subject itself.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question because yes this is possible and [Documented](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax)

Comment: The only thing necessary to make your example work is making the some_method_that_should_return_a_tuple method return an object that can answer to .a_valid_rgb_tuple?.

Comment: @engineersmnky That is not what is meant by "implicit subject" in the link you gave.  There they are talking about what "subject" means when no subject has been defined at all.  In my case I'm talking about having the current subject (whatever it is) be implicitly passed to the matcher.  When I wrote this question, though, I wasn't aware of the notion of implicit/explicit subject as a thing that rspec explicitly defines, so the confusion is fair, and my fault.

Comment: @MikeSnare, there was no confusion on my part, the second example (in the link) shows the setting of `subject` just as, your post and the accepted answer shows. It is called an "explicit subject" because you are explicitly setting it.

Comment: @engineersmnky Right, but that wasn't what I meant by "implicit subject" here.  I was talking about having the subject value "implicitly" passed to the matcher, which is normal behavior, I just had my matcher setup incorrectly to allow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matchers don't actually care about the implicit subject. Matchers just take a actual value and optionally an expected value.

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_multiple_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual % expected == 0
  end
end
```

The implicit subject really is just a matter of how the matcher is called. If you do:

```
subject { 16 }
it { should be_a_multiple_of 4 }
```

Its just a shorthand for `expect(subject).to(be_a_multiple_of(4))`.

A minimal implementation of a matcher for a "RGB tuple"  is:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :be_a_valid_rgb_tuple do
  match do |actual|
    # @todo the boring work of handling bad input such as nil
    # and providing better feedback
    actual.select { |n| n.is_a?(Integer) && (0..255).cover?(n) }.length == 3
  end
end
```

This assumes that by valid "RGB tuple" you mean an array with three integers between 0 and 255.

Comment: Ok.  This was just me being an idiot.  I had defined the matcher more or less correctly, but I had made the the rgb value an argument to the matcher itself, and not the match method IN the matcher.  The result was that the subject was never available in my match method.  So thie answer doesn't _quite_ tell me what I needed, but I will mark it as the answer and update my question with what my problem actually was.

Comment: Its an easy mistake to make. The block arguments to `RSpec::Matchers.define` are the parameters used when initializing the matcher - which is what happens when you call `be_a_multiple_of(4)` and `match do |actual|` defines a `def match(actual)` method which is called on the matcher. Its a pretty clever peice of metaprogramming that can be hard to wrap your head around.

Answer (score 3):

`should be_a_valid_rgb_tuple` is just  `expect(subject).to be_a_valid_rgb_tuple`. It might seem a little less magical with parenthesis.

```
expect(subject()).to(be_a_valid_rgb_tuple())
```

`expect(subject())` just saves the return value of `subject` in an object and returns it. `to` is called on that with the matcher object returned by `be_a_valid_rgb_tuple` and it passes the stored return value to the matcher.

Here is a very rough sketch of how rspec works.

```
class Expectation
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to(matcher)
    raise unless matcher.matches?(@value)
  end
end

class ValidRgbTupleMatcher
  def matches?(value)
    return false unless value.is_a?(RgbTuple)
    return false unless value.valid?
    return true
  end
end

class RgbTuple
  def valid?
    true
  end
end

def expect(value)
  Expectation.new(value)
end

def subject
  RgbTuple.new
end

def be_a_valid_rgb_tuple
  ValidRgbTupleMatcher.new
end

expect(subject).to be_a_valid_rgb_tuple
```

You'd write `be_a_valid_rgb_tuple` as a [custom matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/custom-matchers) and use the normal [one liner syntax](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/subject/one-liner-syntax). Try to write up the matcher using the rspec docs and if you have trouble add a specific question.

---

Though you probably don't need a custom matcher. Instead, use [`be_a`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers) to check the class of the return value, and [`be_valid`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers) to check if its valid. Combine them with [`and`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-10/docs/compound-expectations).

```
it { should be_a(RgbTuple).and be_valid }
```

Equivalent to...

```
it {
  tuple = subject
  expect(tuple.is_a?(RgbTuple)).to be true
  expect(tuple.valid?).to be true
}
```

Comment: In my case an RGB tuple is just an array of ints, so the be_a wouldn't work, nor can I call any custom method on it using be_valid.  Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: @MikeSnare Its an RGB tuple which happens to be implemented as an array of ints. If it's important enough that it needs to be validated, consider turning into an object.